# Insufficient funds error on deploying smart contract

Tags: web3j

I am writing a Java program to deploy a smart contract. I have created the Java Wrapper class. This is the essence of the code.

```
static final BigInteger GAS_PRICE = BigInteger.valueOf(20_000_000_000L);
static final BigInteger GAS_LIMIT = BigInteger.valueOf(4_300_000);
Credentials creds = WalletUtils.loadCredentials(password,
            pathtowalletfile);
Greeter contract = Greeter.deploy(web3j, creds, GAS_PRICE, GAS_LIMIT, BigInteger.ZERO, new Utf8String("Hello")).get();
```

When I run my program I am getting this error

**Error processing transaction request: Insufficient funds for gas * price + value**

I must say that I am quite new to ethereum and web3j. My geth version is 1.6.0-stable-facc47cb

Any help would be much appreciated.

Updated with Contract

```
contract mortal {
    address owner;

    function mortal()  { owner = msg.sender; }
    function kill() { if(msg.sender == owner) suicide(owner); }
}

contract greeter is mortal {
    string greeting;

    function greeter(string _greeting) public {
        greeting = _greeting;
    }

    function greet() constant returns (string) {
        return greeting;
    }
}
```

Comment: check your account balance do you have any ethers?

Comment: Yes, I have. 6.95485869776e+21 is the balance in my account.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am proposing you to define the gas value (higher value) :

```
static final BigInteger GAS = BigInteger.valueOf(30_000);


Greeter contract = Greeter.deploy(web3j, creds, GAS, GAS_PRICE, GAS_LIMIT, BigInteger.ZERO, new Utf8String("Hello")).get();
```

Comment: I tried static final BigInteger GAS = BigInteger.valueOf(30_000); Greeter contract = Greeter.deploy(web3j, creds, GAS, GAS_LIMIT, BigInteger.ZERO, new Utf8String("Hello")).get(); But I still am running into the same error.

Comment: what is the estimated gas of your contract?

Comment: estimated gas is 47123. I increased my gas value to 50000. Still I am getting the same error.

Comment: share with me your contract if it is possible

Comment: I have updated the contract in the question. Thank you for the help.

Comment: The balance I had posted above was the balance of the default account and not of the account in the wallet. I was confused with the wallet account. The account in the wallet did not have sufficient ether. After I transferred ether to this account, it worked. Thank you for your help and time. !